# Tensorflow/Keras GPU memory page fault - CUDA_ERROR_ILLEGAL_ADDRESS with Embedding Layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, gpu

A one-hot encoded array of the same data never has an issue, but creating an embedded array causes a GPU memory page fault, and CUDA_ERROR_ILLEGAL_ADDRESS error when training the model.

The training sometimes can go for a few epochs before throwing an error.

Full log at [errors/CUDA_ERROR_ILLEGAL_ADDRESS.txt](https://github.com/TheShellLand/tenderflow/blob/master/keras/errors/CUDA_ERROR_ILLEGAL_ADDRESS.txt).

Full python file at [lstm_101.py](https://github.com/TheShellLand/tenderflow/blob/master/keras/lstm_101.py#L395)

Function for creating the Embedded aray:

```
def char2vec(dataset):
    """Convert dataset into an integer array for an Embedding layer

    x: Embedded array
    y: one hot encoding array

    :param dataset:
    :return: x, y, samples, timesteps, features, char_to_int, int_to_char
    """

    try:
        raw_text = open(dataset, 'r').read().lower()
        print('[*]', dataset)
    except:
        raise

    chars = sorted(list(set(raw_text)))
    char_to_int = dict((c, i) for i, c in enumerate(chars))
    int_to_char = dict((i, c) for i, c in enumerate(chars))

    nb_chars = raw_text.__len__()
    features = chars.__len__()
    timesteps = seq_length

    # cut the text in semi-redundant sequences of seq_length

    step = 3
    X = []
    Y = []
    for i in range(0, nb_chars - seq_length, step):
        X.append(raw_text[i: i + seq_length])
        Y.append(raw_text[i + seq_length])

    samples = X.__len__()

    print('[*] Corpus Length:', nb_chars)   # 163817
    print('[*] Features:', features)        # 61
    print('[*] Samples:', samples)          # 163761
    print('[*] Timestep:', seq_length)      # 56

    # https://github.com/minimaxir/char-embeddings/blob/master/text_generator_keras.py#L48
    # x = np.zeros((len(sentences), maxlen), dtype=np.int)
    # y = np.zeros((len(sentences), len(chars)), dtype=np.bool)
    # for i, sentence in enumerate(sentences):
    #     for t, char in enumerate(sentence):
    #         X[i, t] = char_indices[char]
    #     y[i, char_indices[next_chars[i]]] = 1

    print('[*] Vectorization...')
    x = np.zeros((samples, seq_length), dtype=np.int32)
    y = np.zeros((samples, features), dtype=np.bool)
    for i, sentence in enumerate(X):
        for t, char in enumerate(sentence):
            x[i, t] = char_to_int[char]
        y[i, char_to_int[Y[i]]] = 1

    return x, y, samples, timesteps, features, char_to_int, int_to_char
```

Model:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(output_dim=64, input_dim=features))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(LSTM(128, return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(LSTM(64))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(features))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
            optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(x, y,
        batch_size=batch_size,
        epochs=epochs,
        verbose=1,
        callbacks=callbacks_list,
        # validation_data=(x_val, y_val),
        # validation_split=0.33,
        shuffle=False,
        initial_epoch=initial_epoch)
```